# Translating names on own OSM tile server?

Tags: openstreetmap, tile-server

I have set up my own tile server following the [Manually building a tile server (14.04)](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) tutorial:

Now i have the problem that the names are localized. Names in Spain are Spanish, in Russia Russian and so on.
I want all labels in English. I understand that there are tags that i can assign to use English names. But where can I use these tags.

I've tried to use a custom lua script, but i think this is the wrong approach.

I am in a real struggle to find tutorials for this task.

Comment: The openstreetmap help site has some solutions: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/20735/country-place-and-street-names-in-english-instead-of-local-language-for-my-own-mapserver and https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/31659/render-maps-with-english-street-labels. Or have a look at http://blog.gegg.us/2013/09/a-simple-way-to-localize-latinize-an-openstreetmap-style/

Comment: Many thanks!!!!!
Somehow i was not able to find these threads with my google skills ...

Answer (score 1):

Use the tag 'name:en'. If there is no 'name:en', use 'name' on its own. In general, localised tags are like ordinary tags with a suffix made from a colon and the two-letter [ISO 639-1 language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).